# Google Drive Picker failing with "docs.google.com refused to connect" after setting Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-picker, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

To support usage of SharedArrayBuffer in our web app we had to add the response headers:
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin

We have also tried:
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: credentialless
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin

The problem with either of these sets of values is that the google drive picker integrated in our application quits working and the google picker panel displays:
docs.google.com refused to connect

If we don't provide a Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy then the google drive picker works as expected.

Comment: Nothing can be done from us, someone posted a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278329600